# Ruby: divisible by 4

Tags: ruby, modulo

This works fine, but I want to make it prettier - and accommodate all values that are divisible by 4:

```
if i==4 || i==8 || i==12 || i==16 || i==20 || i==24 || i==28 || i==32
  # ...
end
```

Any clever, short method to do this?

Comment: FWIW, the proper solution to this specific problem aside, when you have long lists of equal comparisons on the same object, you can cut it down to `[4, 8, 12].include?(i)`.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Try this:

```
if i % 4 == 0
```

This is called the "[modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)".

Comment: @snowangel: I had to finish my tea. Otherwise I would have answered two minutes earlier :-)

Comment: Be aware that if i is a string like '8' this will silently fail and return '8' not 0. There is no type coercion going on here. So make sure i is an Integer.

Comment: @TJChambers: it would not "fail". % operator has different meaning on strings, that's all.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - absolutely correct - so make sure it is not a string.

Comment: @TJChambers: this is not javascript, you know. We don't normally mix types like that. Also, string is not mentioned anywhere on the page. So I'm confused, as to what prompted your comment. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - my comment was from direct experience in Ruby where "i" could be any Object, String, Integer, etc. For those who may have retrieved i from a source where other operations on it involve implicit type coercion, this particular action DOES not. That was my intent - since if i was a String, the statement above unlike the next answer would not perhaps return the desired results in operation, but would not cause any error at runtime to announce that a String was being operated upon. Such is the condition of a non-static typed language.

Answer (score 51):

There's also `modulo`, which allows you to do

```
420.modulo(4).zero?
```

There's nothing stopping you doing that with `%`, but it looks weird:

```
420.%(4).zero?
```

Comment: Sergio Tulentsev's answer is the way I've always done it, but I really like this one better -- it's so much more pleasing to the eyeball!

Comment: Unlike the previous answer above, if you take this route and the variable is NOT an Integer or Float subclass, you WILL get a Runtime error.

Answer (score 16):

This is always a good conversation starter:

```
if (i & 3).zero?
```

Comment: The age of this answer and lack of comments made me laugh :P

Comment: `i.nobits?(3)` in Ruby 2.5+