# How to include a 'next if' condition in an inline loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, slim-lang

I would like to include `next if` in this loop:

```
 = select_tag :type, options_for_select(Products.statuses.keys.map{ |product_type| [I18n.t("product.#{product_type}"), product_type] }, params[:type])
```

So I would like something as:

```
 Products.statuses.keys.map{ |product_type| next if product_type == "clothes", [I18n.t("product.#{product_type}"), product_type] }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a list you can always [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Array.html#method-i-select) or [`reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Array.html#method-i-reject) elements based on condition:

```
Products.statuses
        .keys
        .reject { |product_type| product_type == "clothes" } # <= won't be in list
        .map    { |product_type| [I18n.t("product.#{product_type}"), product_type] }
```

Comment: y u be so fast? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yesterday I had the same question to you! mean, you answered something literally few seconds after the question appeared and I was like 'hoow?' :D

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: haha, check out [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8817942/125816).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ... <7 seconds, it is just hard to believe!

Answer (score 1):

You have it almost correct: the expression separator in Ruby is a semicolon `;`, not a comma `,`, so it should be

```
Products.statuses.keys.map{ |product_type| next if product_type == "clothes"; [I18n.t("product.#{product_type}"), product_type] }
#                                                                          ↑↑↑
```

You could also invert the logic and write it like this:

```
Products.statuses.keys.map{ |product_type| next [I18n.t("product.#{product_type}"), product_type] unless product_type == "clothes" }
```

Comment: the problem with this is that skipped iterations will produce `nil` in mapped results.

Comment: Yes, as would the OP's code without the syntax error. I am assuming that's the intent.

Comment: I'm betting that this is not the intent and the question is a classic example of XY problem.

Comment: You can call `compact` at the end.